# Align section with text body

Tags: formatting

I am trying to align the title of a section with the following body, so that the section number has a negative margin w.r.t. the body of the text. See here:

[image]

The following MWE tries to create the above output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\LARGE\bfseries}% format applied to label+text
  {\hspace{-40pt} \LARGE\bfseries\thesection}% label
  {20pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

\begin{document}
\section{asd}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Of course, the manual `\hspace{-40pt}` is what I would like to avoid. Is there a way to determine the width of `\thesection`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way could be to use a right aligned box of zero width:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\LARGE\bfseries}% format applied to label+text
  {\makebox[0cm][r]{\thesection\hspace{20pt}}}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

\begin{document}
\section{asd}
\blindtext

\addtocounter{section}{1000}
\section{asd}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]